# Resgatar nome ao invés de id em um select option vindo do banco de dados PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite,

Estou populando um select option com dados vindo do banco, mas na hora de recuperar o valor, eu quero recuperar o nome ao invés do id..tem como fazer isso?

```
//chama o arquivo de configuração com o banco
 require_once("connection.php");

$q = 'SELECT id, user_name FROM users';

<select list="user" onkeyup="check_in_db()" class="message-input" name="user_name" id="user_name">
        <option>Selecione um usuario para enviar mensagem...</option>   

              <?php $r = mysqli_query($con, $q) ;
                if($r){
                  if(mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0){
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)){ ?>
              <option  value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['user_name'] ?></option>
              <?php } 
            }
          }?>
      </select>
```

Quero recuperar o nome de **user_name** do option, ao invés de id... pq faço uma verificação e gravo esse **user_name** em outra tabela do banco de dados, por isso presciso recuperar o nome deste option, sei que é uma pergunta boba, mas estou iniciando no PHP, agradeço a quem puder me ajudar...

Comment: Bastaria substituir o $row['id'] por $row['NomeDeQualquerCampo']... Porém a melhor prática em banco de dados relacionais recomenda que você mantenha o nome de usuário em uma tabela e referencie esse nome pelo ID em qualquer outro lugar onde seja preciso, seja por meio de chave estrangeira (FK) ou por substituição (surrogate Key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu bem entendi, você quer que o mesmo valor exibido para o usuário no comboBox seja salvo também correto? Pois o valor exibido é o user_name.

É bem simples na verdade, apenas faça isso:

```
 <option  value="<?php echo $row['user_name'] ?>"><?php echo $row['user_name'] ?></option>
```

Troque o valor dentro de **value** de id para user_name.

Comment: funcionou, perfeito, muito obrigado!